# Why use a variable in a bash regex match inside [[?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, quoting, test

There is not a simple answer to this question at this site yet.
This question aims to give a simple and clear answer.

It is usually recommended to use a variable (`$regex`) in this construct:

```
if [[ $var =~ $regex ]]; then …
```

Why is that so?

Comment: @Isaac I'm having trouble seeing how this isn't a duplicate of the post Stéphane Chazelas linked

Comment: @MichaelMrozek IMhO!!: that post is complex, this aims to be simpler, more general. This post already has more than 1000 views (in 3 months), the other still has less than 700 (after a year). It was a message of this reaching 1000 views that prompted me to look back into it. Maybe you could merge both. Maybe keep the title and question of this post and place both answers together. It is your call ... if you still see a more visited question (more relevant to people searching for solutions) as the duplicate then mark it as such. If so, I probably should just erase it, no longer helpful.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan; will merge your answer into the other post and keep this question as a duplicate pointer since more people seem to be finding this one when they search for the issue